# How to deserialize this Json string in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am getting error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll
',' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 10 | BytePositionInLine: 2.
```

Code:

```
        public class InstrumentData
        {
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Id")] 
            public int Id { get; set; }
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Kind")]
            public string Kind { get; set; }
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Date")]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Status")]
            public string Status { get; set; }
            //[JsonInclude]
            //[JsonPropertyName("Value")]
            public double Value { get; set; }
            //public Object Properties { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string jsonFile = "C:\\Users\\Piotr\\Documents\\Assets-battery\\ASSETID-2486-response_1694084415096.json";
            //string jsondata = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
            string jsondata =    " {                                              \n" +
                                 "   \"Id\": 4897244,                             \n" +
                                 "   \"Type\": \"InstrumentVoltage\",             \n" +
                                 "   \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
                                 "   \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
                                 "   \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
                                 "   \"Value\": 12.75,                            \n" +
                                 "   \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
                                 "     \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
                                 "   }                                            \n" +
                                 " },                                             \n" +
                                 " {                                              \n" +
                                 "   \"Id\": 4897245,                             \n" +
                                 "   \"Type\": \"BatteryPercent\",                \n" +
                                 "   \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
                                 "   \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
                                 "   \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
                                 "   \"Value\": 99,                               \n" +
                                 "   \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
                                 "     \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
                                 "   }                                            \n" +
                                 " },                                             \n";
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                AllowTrailingCommas = true
            };


            InstrumentData data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InstrumentData>(jsondata, options);
        }
    }
```

BTW I want to skip the `"Properties"` part of the record.

Comment: You are not deserializing what that json is _and_ the json is missing surrounding `[]`. Since there seem to be two items, it needs to be a json array. And thus, you'll also need to deserialize that array / collection.

Comment: @Fildor what is "Json array"? 2. There is nothing like this in the Microsft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YeTJw

Comment: A set of items in json is represented as "[ item1, item2 ]". That's commonly referred to as a json array. the items could then be literals/single values, objects or again arrays. See also: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @Fildor thank you very much. Please write an answer and I will accept it ASAP

Comment: From the error my guess is [`JsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.allowtrailingcommas?view=net-7.0). that defaults to false. System.Text.Json is more strict with regards to formatting than say Json.Net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

1. The json is not right. You have two items, so this should probably be an array. ( A set of items in json is represented as "[ item1, item2 ]". That's commonly referred to as a json array. the items could then be literals/single values, objects or again arrays. See also: https://json.org/json-en.html )
2. Having an array, you'll also need to deserialize to an array (or collection).

I made a little Fiddle to show the fix:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsondata =    " [{                                              \n" +
                                 "   \"Id\": 4897244,                             \n" +
                                 "   \"Type\": \"InstrumentVoltage\",             \n" +
                                 "   \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
                                 "   \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
                                 "   \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
                                 "   \"Value\": 12.75,                            \n" +
                                 "   \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
                                 "     \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
                                 "   }                                            \n" +
                                 " },                                             \n" +
                                 " {                                              \n" +
                                 "   \"Id\": 4897245,                             \n" +
                                 "   \"Type\": \"BatteryPercent\",                \n" +
                                 "   \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
                                 "   \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
                                 "   \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
                                 "   \"Value\": 99,                               \n" +
                                 "   \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
                                 "     \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
                                 "   }                                            \n" +
                                 " }]";  
        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InstrumentData[]>(jsondata);
        result.Dump();
    }
}

public class InstrumentData
        {
            
            public int Id { get; set; }
            
            public string Type { get; set; }
            
            public string Kind { get; set; }
            
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            
            public string Status { get; set; }
            
            public double Value { get; set; }
            
        }
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YeTJw

You also did have a trailing comma. That *can* also be a problem with the default settings, but you *can* allow it providing serializer options. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.allowtrailingcommas?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-allowtrailingcommas

Comment: A nice addition to make writing json to this could be [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) `@""` using this you do not need to start a new string every single newline

Comment: @Roe, I just used OP's code as much as possible. And I guess _actually_ the data is read from a file or network, so that's that.

Comment: Completely agree that you took the correct route, just thought i would leave this comment in case people do have to write strings like this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your json contains two items but your Deserialize expects only one.
2. Your json is not valid because you need surrounding `"[" "]"` brackets if you want a list/array of data.

Solution:

```
var multibleData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<InstrumentData>>(jsondata, options);
```

and

```
string jsondata = 
    " [ \n" +
    "   { \n" +
    "     \"Id\": 4897244,                             \n" +
    "     \"Type\": \"InstrumentVoltage\",             \n" +
    "     \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
    "     \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
    "     \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
    "     \"Value\": 12.75,                            \n" +
    "     \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
    "       \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
    "     }                                            \n" +
    "   },                                             \n" +
    "   {                                              \n" +
    "     \"Id\": 4897245,                             \n" +
    "     \"Type\": \"BatteryPercent\",                \n" +
    "     \"Kind\": \"Value\",                         \n" +
    "     \"Date\": \"2023-01-06T17:40:14\",           \n" +
    "     \"Status\": \"Official\",                    \n" +
    "     \"Value\": 99,                               \n" +
    "     \"Properties\": {                            \n" +
    "       \"OriginalStatus\": \"Official\"           \n" +
    "     }                                            \n" +
    "   }   \n" +
    " ]     \n";
```